# Java flexjson Serializing composed JSON objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, flexjson

I have a Java class and I want to generate a JSON string from an object of the class. However, the members of the class are as follows:

```
/**
 * The set containing the footer texts
 */
public HeaderOrFooter[] footers = null;
/**
 * The title of the word cloud
 */
public HeaderOrFooter title;
/**
 * The subtitle of the word cloud
 */
public HeaderOrFooter subTitle;
/**
 * The set of rectangles to be drawn
 */
public Rectangle[] rectangles;
/**
 * The set of round rectangles to be drawn
 */
public RoundRectangle[] roundRectangles;
/**
 * The set of lines to be drawn
 */
public Line[] lines;
/**
 * The set of polygons to be drawn
 */
public Polygon[] polygons;
/**
 * The set of words to be drawn
 */
public Word[] words;
```

and my method which converts the object to JSON looks like this:

```
public String convertToJSON()
{
    flexjson.JSONSerializer jsonSerializer = new flexjson.JSONSerializer();
    jsonSerializer.exclude("class");
    jsonSerializer.exclude("subTitle.class");
    jsonSerializer.exclude("title.class");
    return jsonSerializer.serialize(this);
}
```

I am using `flexjson` and its `JSONSerializer` object. My problem is that it only converts the title and subTitle members to JSON, the arrays are not converted. Can somebody tell me how could I include the arrays to my JSON? Thanks.

Comment: Have you given the arrays a value with `new Line[1]` or something similar? After that you fill in the `Line` object(s).

Comment: The arrays are filled with value. I can serialize them separately, but I would like to generate the JSON from my object containing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out, here it is the correct function:

```
// Re-using the serializer as per "Thread Safety and Reuse"
// section of http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/
public static final flexjson.JSONSerializer jsonSerializer;
static {
    jsonSerializer = new flexjson.JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class");
}

public String toJSON() {
    return jsonSerializer.deepSerialize(this);
}
```